# Android UI for multiple devices

Tags: android

Is there a way to ensure that my Android UI will display as expected across different phones ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go through the [developers guide on supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). It gives you all information on that topic.

Answer (score 3):

This would be the first stop I would recommend:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> "This document explains the
>   screens-support features provided by
>   the platform and how you use them in
>   your application. By following the
>   practices described here, you can
>   easily create an application that
>   displays properly on all supported
>   device screens and that you can deploy
>   to any device as a single .apk."to any device as a single .apk."

Answer (score 3):

In your build.gradle(Module: app) add these dependencies:

```
//for dynamic ui change
implementation "com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5"
implementation "com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4"
```

In your dimen.xml file add these lines:

```
<dimen name="dimen_1dp">@dimen/_1sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_2dp">@dimen/_2sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_3dp">@dimen/_3sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_4dp">@dimen/_4sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_5dp">@dimen/_5sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_6dp">@dimen/_6sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_7dp">@dimen/_7sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_8dp">@dimen/_8sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_9dp">@dimen/_9sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_10dp">@dimen/_10sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_11dp">@dimen/_11sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_12dp">@dimen/_12sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_13dp">@dimen/_13sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_14dp">@dimen/_14sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_15dp">@dimen/_15sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_16dp">@dimen/_16sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_17dp">@dimen/_17sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_18dp">@dimen/_18sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_19dp">@dimen/_19sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_20dp">@dimen/_20sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_21dp">@dimen/_21sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_22dp">@dimen/_22sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_23dp">@dimen/_23sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_24dp">@dimen/_24sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_25dp">@dimen/_25sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_26dp">@dimen/_26sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_27dp">@dimen/_27sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_28dp">@dimen/_28sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_29dp">@dimen/_29sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_30dp">@dimen/_30sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_31dp">@dimen/_31sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_32dp">@dimen/_32sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_33dp">@dimen/_33sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_34dp">@dimen/_34sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_35dp">@dimen/_35sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_36dp">@dimen/_36sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_37dp">@dimen/_37sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_38dp">@dimen/_38sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_39dp">@dimen/_39sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_40dp">@dimen/_40sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_41dp">@dimen/_41sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_42dp">@dimen/_42sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_43dp">@dimen/_43sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_44dp">@dimen/_44sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_45dp">@dimen/_45sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_46dp">@dimen/_46sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_47dp">@dimen/_47sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_48dp">@dimen/_48sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_49dp">@dimen/_49sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_50dp">@dimen/_50sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_51dp">@dimen/_51sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_52dp">@dimen/_52sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_53dp">@dimen/_53sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_54dp">@dimen/_54sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_55dp">@dimen/_55sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_56dp">@dimen/_56sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_57dp">@dimen/_57sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_58dp">@dimen/_58sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_59dp">@dimen/_59sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_60dp">@dimen/_60sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_61dp">@dimen/_61sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_62dp">@dimen/_62sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_63dp">@dimen/_63sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_64dp">@dimen/_64sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_65dp">@dimen/_65sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_66dp">@dimen/_66sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_67dp">@dimen/_67sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_68dp">@dimen/_68sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_69dp">@dimen/_69sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_70dp">@dimen/_70sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_71dp">@dimen/_71sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_72dp">@dimen/_72sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_73dp">@dimen/_73sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_74dp">@dimen/_74sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_75dp">@dimen/_75sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_76dp">@dimen/_76sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_77dp">@dimen/_77sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_78dp">@dimen/_78sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_79dp">@dimen/_79sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_80dp">@dimen/_80sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_81dp">@dimen/_81sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_82dp">@dimen/_82sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_83dp">@dimen/_83sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_84dp">@dimen/_84sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_85dp">@dimen/_85sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_86dp">@dimen/_86sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_87dp">@dimen/_87sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_88dp">@dimen/_88sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_89dp">@dimen/_89sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_90dp">@dimen/_90sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_91dp">@dimen/_91sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_92dp">@dimen/_92sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_93dp">@dimen/_93sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_94dp">@dimen/_94sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_95dp">@dimen/_95sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_96dp">@dimen/_96sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_97dp">@dimen/_97sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_98dp">@dimen/_98sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_99dp">@dimen/_99sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_100dp">@dimen/_100sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_105dp">@dimen/_105sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_110dp">@dimen/_110sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_112dp">@dimen/_112sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_115dp">@dimen/_115sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_120dp">@dimen/_120sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_125dp">@dimen/_125sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_130dp">@dimen/_130sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_135dp">@dimen/_135sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_140dp">@dimen/_140sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_145dp">@dimen/_145sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_150dp">@dimen/_150sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_160dp">@dimen/_160sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_170dp">@dimen/_170sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_180dp">@dimen/_180sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_190dp">@dimen/_190sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_200dp">@dimen/_200sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_203dp">@dimen/_203sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_205dp">@dimen/_205sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_210dp">@dimen/_210sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_215dp">@dimen/_215sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_220dp">@dimen/_220sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_230dp">@dimen/_230sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_250dp">@dimen/_250sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_300dp">@dimen/_300sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_400dp">@dimen/_400sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_450dp">@dimen/_450sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_500dp">@dimen/_500sdp</dimen>
<dimen name="dimen_600dp">@dimen/_600sdp</dimen>


<!--FONT-->
<dimen name="font_5sp">@dimen/_5ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_8sp">@dimen/_8ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_9sp">@dimen/_9ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_10sp">@dimen/_10ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_11sp">@dimen/_11ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_12sp">@dimen/_12ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_13sp">@dimen/_13ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_14sp">@dimen/_14ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_15sp">@dimen/_15ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_16sp">@dimen/_16ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_17sp">@dimen/_17ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_18sp">@dimen/_18ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_19sp">@dimen/_19ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_20sp">@dimen/_20ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_21sp">@dimen/_21ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_22sp">@dimen/_22ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_23sp">@dimen/_23ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_24sp">@dimen/_24ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_25sp">@dimen/_25ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_26sp">@dimen/_26ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_27sp">@dimen/_27ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_28sp">@dimen/_28ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_29sp">@dimen/_29ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_30sp">@dimen/_30ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_31sp">@dimen/_31ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_32sp">@dimen/_32ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_33sp">@dimen/_33ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_34sp">@dimen/_34ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_35sp">@dimen/_35ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_36sp">@dimen/_36ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_37sp">@dimen/_37ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_38sp">@dimen/_38ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_39sp">@dimen/_39ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_40sp">@dimen/_40ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_41sp">@dimen/_41ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_42sp">@dimen/_42ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_43sp">@dimen/_43ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_44sp">@dimen/_44ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_45sp">@dimen/_45ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_46sp">@dimen/_46ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_47sp">@dimen/_47ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_48sp">@dimen/_48ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_49sp">@dimen/_49ssp</dimen>
<dimen name="font_50sp">@dimen/_50ssp</dimen>
```

You can add more dimension according to the requirement in your project.

In your XML file suppose you are using TextView you can use this dimension from the dimen.xml folder as given below :

```
 <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvName"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_30dp"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_30dp"
       android:textSize="@dimen/font_8sp"
       android:text="Name" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two major considerations for multiple devices:

1. Make sure your app handles orientation changes well for phones with or without hardware keyboards
2. Display your UI elements relative to the screen size.

On the latter point, if you declare everything using literal pixel values, there is a chance a specific device's screen will be too big, or too small to render things right. However, if you size everything relative to the screen size, everything will always be in the right place.